# How to make rotated word and rotated line using HTML5 without using canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on one project in which i want to draw a angle line and at the end of line i have to put one angle character . but i don't want to use canvas because requirement is user can select any of those line by clicking on it . this might not possible through canvas . Give me some suggestion .

Actually I want to draw following image and Also can select one or multiple lines available in it .
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the css `transform` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily possible on canvas, but I would suggest SVG for this. You can find a very good SVG library here http://raphaeljs.com/, Or you could use a canvas library also, http://kineticjs.com/.

To accomplish this on your own using canvas, you simply have to track the mouse co-ordinates on the canvas in a `mousemove event` then on a `click` event work out the mouse position relative to your line, if the mouse click was inside your line you have a click on the line.

Without supplying any code or anything you have tried so far I cannot go into more detail as this is a very broad and generic question not really tied to any one thing.

Comment: I attached image with the question .

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you use [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/) library. It will allow you to manipulate each line as separate layers and you can also attach mouse and touch events to those layers very easily. It is pretty easy to learn and understand as it is based on jQuery and the syntax is almost similar to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at animate CSS3 feature: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style> 
 div
 {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 position:relative;
 animation-name:mymove;
 animation-duration:5s;

 /* Safari and Chrome */
 -webkit-animation-name:mymove;
 -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
 }

 @keyframes mymove
 {
 from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotate(-90deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
 {
 from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
 to {-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); }
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-name property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

 <div></div>

 <p><b>Note:</b> Always specify the animation-duration property. Otherwise the duration      is 0, and the animation will not be played.</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```